# Mail function in PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm using PHP for sending an e-mail. The values in the e-mail are depending on the inputs of a form. But for some reason, the mail is suddenly not sending. It did before. What's wrong with my code?

Orders are placed correctly in the database, so no error there.

```
if ($order->addOrder($_DB)) {
$user       = "SafetyCam.be";                               
$verzonden      = FALSE;                            

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
    $lastname   = $_POST['lastname'];
    $address    = $_POST['address'];
    $zip        = $_POST['zip'];
    $place      = $_POST['place'];
    $country    = $_POST['country'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $twogig = $_POST['vn_qty'];
    $fourgig    = $_POST['ja_qty'];
    $total      = $_POST['total'];

    $totaal = (($twogig * 50) + ($fourgig *80) + 2.5);

    $headers    = 'From: info@something.be';

$to     = 'me@gmail.com';
$subject    = 'Bevestiging bestelling';
$message    = 'Hello $firstname,

        You placed the following order on our website.

        - $twogig x 2GB SafetyCams ordered
        - $fourgig x 4GB SafetyCams ordered
        + shippingcosts (2,5 EUR)

        The total cost for this order amounts to $totaal EUR.

        Your products will be delivered as quickly as possible after receipt of your payment. 
        Please transfer the order amount of $totaal EUR into account X.                     

        After payment, the products will be sent to the following address:

        $firstname $lastname
        $address
        $zip $place
        $country

        We hope you will be very happy with your purchase.

        Sincerely yours";


     if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                $verzonden  = TRUE;
                $feedback    = '<div class="feedbackheader">Thanks</div><br / >';

            } else {
                $verzonden  = FALSE;
                $feedback    = '<div class="feedbackheader">Error!</div>';              }
            } 
        else {
            $feedback    = '<div class="feedbackheader">Error!</div>';
        }
}
```

Comment: the code is incomplete, please paste the rest of the code...

Comment: Are you seriously not sanitizing any data inputted by the user?

Comment: sorry, the code is complete, but it has formatting problems..

Comment: please replace "$message    = 'Hello $firstname," with "$message    = "Hello $firstname," (you have to use double quote instead of simple quote.

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen, what do you mean by sanitizing? Double quote trick didn't work...

Comment: It has nothing to do with your original question, but you are not sanitizing the data being supplied by the user filling out the form. You are setting yourself up for code injection attacks.

Comment: Ok. And how can I sanitize my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SwiftMailer:

```
require_once('../lib/swiftMailer/lib/swift_required.php');
function sendEmail(){
  //Sendmail
  $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

  //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

  $body="Dear $fname,\n\nYour job application was successful. \n\nYours,\n\nEamorr\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";


  //Create a message
  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject goes here')
    ->setFrom(array($email => "no-reply@yourdomain.com"))
    ->setTo(array($email => "$fname $lname"))
    ->setBody($body);

  //Send the message
  $result = $mailer->send($message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you open your mail $message with a single quote and end it in a double quote.

You should open and end with both double quotes, especially since you use PHP variables inside.

```
$message    = 'Hello $firstname"; //Wrong

$message = "Hello $firstname"; // Works
```

Answer (score 1):

You've opened the "message" string with an apostrophe `'` but tried to close it with a quotation mark `"`. The SO syntax highlighter gives it away!

Answer (score 1):

You have started your variable `$message    = 'Hello $firstname,` with single quote and end it with double quote, what you need to do is just make

```
$message = "Hello $firstname
```

if you put it in single quote php wont scan your variable content for varible like $firstname

Answer (score 1):

Your `$message` variable starts the string with a `'` but ends it with a `"`, so all the code after it is included in the variable until another `'` which happens when your defining `$feedback`.

Basically you are not closing the string, and therefore your entire code is being changed. If you are using color coding you should have seen this (I can see it from your question).

Also, if you are using single quotes, you cannot use inline variables.

```
$var    = 1;
echo '$var'; // ouput: $var;
echo "$var"; // output: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You start your message-string with a single quote (') and try to end it with a double quote, thus your logic is parsed incorrectly.